# Need a way to get the version # used by the msi installer at run time in c#, without knowing the location of the msi file used to install

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm developing a scheme to automatically update my program from a central point. To assist me in this I need a way to get the version # of the msi file used to install the progarm at runtime, so I can compare the installed version with the latest version on the server (already solved this part) and decide whether or not to update. To be clear, I already have a way of opening up msi files using msi.dll and getting the version # out. The problem is one of bootstrapping. If the user installs the program for the very first time, how can my program know where to find the msi file (on the client)?

The solution can be as simple as the msi creating a text file with the version # in it when it runs. I'd like to avoid querying the registry if I can.

If I can't figure this out I'm going to have to take special care to keep the version #'s the same in the GUI project and also the MSI installer, and that thought annoys me.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

I assume you want to get the ProductVersion property of the MSI.

You can do this fairly easily using COM.

Add a COM reference to "Microsoft Windows Installer Object Library" to your C# project.

Then try the following program:

```
namespace TestCS
{
    using System;
    using WindowsInstaller;

    internal class Test
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length < 1)
            {
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(GetMsiVersion(args[0]));
        }

        private static string GetMsiVersion(string installerPath)
        {
            Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
            Installer inst = (Installer)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            Database d = inst.OpenDatabase(
                installerPath, 
                MsiOpenDatabaseMode.msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly);
            View v = d.OpenView(
                "SELECT * FROM Property WHERE Property = 'ProductVersion'");
            v.Execute(null);
            Record r = v.Fetch();
            string result = r.get_StringData(2);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose I could do it this way if I had my auto updater place the msi file it executes in the same spot all the time, and keeps it there.

Comment: I just need to find a way to confirm that the MSI installation was a success before I copy the new msi over the old one, do you know how I'd do that?

Comment: Not sure about that last question - depends on how you are launching the installation. If you are controlling the installation process you can just check the return code from the installation...there's also an event that gets written to the event log you might be able to fetch.

Comment: yeah i think i'll execute the msi with the command line methods with /quiet after it, and make my own little progress report on the console screen. Now I just have to experiment with those return codes.

Comment: Sorry I didn't accept your answer, but maybe my question wasn't clear enough. I've already used a similar scheme to get the version # of the most current msi on the server. However, when it comes to the client, when the client runs the program it would be nice to do this again but I don't a way of knowing beforehand where the msi that was used to install the program is. Is there some kind of registry magic I can work to get the installed version #?

Answer (score 0):

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` registry key contains ProductCode subkeys of installed programs.  Control Panel's "Add/Remove Problems" and MSI Engine work with this branch.

Iterating through these subkeys you can find the GUID of your program (if you keep old value when changing version in Setup-and-Deployment project).  Under that subkey 'DisplayVersion' string value will contain installed version (corresponds to 'Version' property in SnD project).

If you do change ProductCode when increasing Version number (as VisualStudio recommends), 'DisplayName' string may be useful for figuring out which subkey is representing your program, it corresponds to 'ProductName' property in SnD project.

Some programs may be listed in `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` when installed on a per-user basis (e.g. via ClickOnce).
On 64-bit systems there's `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` for 32-bit programs in addition to the original, which in that environment keeps track of 64-bit ones.